# Java Script to get/combine data from multiple Google Sheets that are stored in different folders (archives)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying a script to scrape data form a given Sheetname and a given range into 1 main sheet. the problem in this case is that the Spreadsheets (with multiple sheets) are archived in different folders. so I have 1 main folder and in that folder I have archive folders for every year (2012-2022).

I have made script that is going through these folders and get the folder Id's that part is working.

I also have made a script to get the data from the sheet ("Rekenblad") and the range "A11:AY136". I think that also should work.

The part where I connect those 2 function is going wrong. What I would recieve is:

A main file (The script is inside the main file) with:

1. A sheet (blad1) with a list of all the information of the file
2. A sheet (blad2) with all data ranges combined. Every time I run this script the data needs to be cleared so I dont have doubles.

The most important is point 2. point 1 is just for me to check if all files are imported correctly and a link so I can easily check those files.

Script looks like this:

```
    function listFolders(folder) {

   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().clearContents();
   sheet.appendRow(["Name", "URL","ssId", "Type"]);
   var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER_ID_PARENT_FOLDER");

  var subfolders = folder.getFolders();
  
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
       //Logger.log(folder);
    var name = subfolders.next();
    while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
       //Logger.log(folder);
    var name = subfolders.next();

    var files = name.getFiles();

    var cnt = 0;
    var file;
    var ssID
    var fileType
    var combinedData = []

    while (files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();
        cnt++;

        Logger.log(file);
        Logger.log(cnt);

            data = [
                file.getName(),
                file.getUrl(),
                ssID = file.getId(),
                fileType = file.getMimeType(),
            ];

            sheet.appendRow(data);  
            if (fileType ==="application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"){
              ssID = files.getId();
              data = GetData(ssID)
              data = data.map(function(r){return r.concat([file.getName()]);});
              combinedData = combinedData.concat(data);
            }
    }
    var wss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Blad1") ;
    ws.getRange("A2:AY").clearContent();

    wss.getRange(2, 1, combinedData.length, combinedData[0].length).setValues(combinedData);     
    }
  }
}   


function GetData(ssID){

  var aa = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  var wa = aa.getSheetByName("Rekenblad");
  var info = wa.getRange("A11:AY136").getValues();
  return info
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to have the sample spreadsheet that you are using so it is possible to also test it?

Comment: Hi Ricardo,

Herewith a link to a test folder with a sample data set because thats easier to read.
 https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Ee9LiHyd0QLvs6fndn6IOqNG4mFMVz3Q 
I also saw that the logger that is logging the sheet information like name and size is not working correctly. it is scanning through the files but it is missing 1 folder.

They are in de file as 2 separated scripts

Comment: Could you share more details about what is exactly failing with your process? if you can share an expected output and current output would be as well helpful so we can have a better idea of what the problem is.